# BoxConstraints forces an infinite height[error]

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

This is my code..
I am getting error saying that 'BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.' and then a description and i am new to flutter i am not getting a way to solve this.

```
  body:SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: [
        Image(
          color: Colors.black12,
          colorBlendMode: BlendMode.darken,
          image: AssetImage('images/Alone.jpg'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Show('Alone is Stronger', 'y'),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

This is my Show widget.

```
Widget Show(String x,String y){
return
    Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 2),
    width: 400,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white10,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    ),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: Text(
      '$x',
          style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20,
         fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      color: Colors.yellowAccent,
           ),
        ),
     ); 
  }
```

Lot of questions already here with same problem but i am not getting where the problem is.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to have a background image on body?

Comment: @yeasinSheikh, Yes i want to have a background image fixed on body and the text part to be scrollable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code-snippet, I can understand you are trying to have a background on `body`.

`SingleChildScrollView` provide infinite height and while `Stack` is its child and use parent size, it will get infinite height and through errors.

In your case, the widget structure will be

```dart
  body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          Image(
            color: Colors.black12,
            colorBlendMode: BlendMode.darken,
            image: AssetImage('images/Alone.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Show('Alone is Stronger', 'y'),
            ],
          ))
        ],
      ),
```